# Exporting just posts of a specific category

Tags: categories, import, export

I have found the export tool particularly useful for moving posts from sites to site, and even once wrote an extension for Elgg to export its content into wordpress export format for migration to BuddyPress.

However, I now find I'd like to export just the posts of a single category, so that I can put those posts on a different wordpress install whilst leaving the other posts on the original site. Given the number of posts on the site, I'd rather not have to export everything and manually edit the xml file.

Is there a way I can export posts of just one category into a standard wordpress import/export xml file?

The site being imported to is on the same multisite install, with shared user base, so post and comment attribution should be preserved.

Comment: Be aware that plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq] and it is hard to read "is there a tool" in any other way.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Noted. Do you suggest I reword the question or withdraw it?

Comment: A minor rewording should do it, but it is still a pretty broad question. Have you done research? Do you have any code that you have been working on, working or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default exporter will do this. Instead of selecting "All Content", choose "Post" and then a category.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I didn't realise the form would expand if I selected 'Posts' so I wrongly assumed it just meant 'all posts'.

Comment: sorry to bring this up, but how can rearrange /reorder the exported .xml file before i import it again?

Comment: @alex, not easily and not without considerable risk. The exported file is just a flat text file. It isn't manipulable, though you could build a script to open it, parse it, reorder it, and resave it.

Answer (score 0):

## Trick for Custom-Post-Types:

As CPTs don't show those options, that **post** radio checkbox shows, you will need to modify the input from **Browser>Inspect** :

`<input type="radio" name="content" value="CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_HEREE">`

[image]