# Category as Subdomain for One WP Install

Tags: plugins, categories, multisite, sitemap

Please I need help, I have a blog with already over 80k post (One WP Install). For Person reasons I want to change one of the category to a subdomain. I have searched for a plugin for that and it works fine. Using [Main category as subdomain Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/main-category-as-subdomain/).

But I have issue now, because I want an xml sitemap on the subdomains, and the above plugin does not have sitemap included in it. I have spent over 2 weeks trying to create out sitemap to with work only on the subdomain specifically, but No way out. my default Xml sitemap is not getting the subdomain included.

I want to know if I can use A multisite network to achieve my goal. and delete the Main Category as subdomain Plugin. because I really want my already posted content from that category on a subdomain, including sitemap on it.

Comment: Some steps you should think about are: Server preparing for subdomains *(you already seem to have)*. Export those [category postings](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102746/15605). Creating a [multisite/network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite)  *(I personally wouldn't convert a single to multi site but that is up to you)* Import postings into that subdomain and so on. In short, yes you can achieve your goal using a multisite network.

Comment: I am scared that some of my plugins won't work on multisite. and I am also scared that [Google xml sitemap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) will not work on multi site.

Comment: and I also want the post url to display on the homepage of my rootdomain site.